# The Height of the graph in ssrs does not align with Y axis

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005, reportbuilder

Currently I working on report that need to visualize graphical bar chart using SSRS report for customer engagement by using report builder.

However the height of the bar chart populated is not align with Y axis. Refer the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of graph]

You can see that bar for 2022-05 is showing 2516 however the height of bar is reach until 2000. By right it should be above value of 2000 at Y-axis and same goes to others months.

My Y-axis option have configured as Auto for Minimum, Maximum and Interval and type of interval set as Numbers.

[image: Screenshot of Y-axis option]

Seek for any idea how to solve this height issue

Comment: It looks like you're using second axis for the chart, but are only showing one.

Comment: What you mean second axis for the chart but only showing one?

Comment: Right-Click the bar on the chart, then "Series Properties", then "Axes and Chart Data" and then check the "Vertical axis" setting. if this is set to Secondary then you are using the 2nd axis but not showing it. Right-Click the chart area just above the bar and then check the "Show Secondary Vertical Axis" option

Comment: This way works!!! Thank you for the advise

But want to further clarify is possible to to use one Y-axis to for two bar?

Comment: Yes but the axis will sclare across both series

Comment: Can provide step to combine two bar based on one Y axis?

Comment: Is it update green bar to become primary axis?